# Understanding strange output in multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to ruby and I was trying to iterate over a 2d array. I made a mistake in my code. From that mistake, I noticed some unexpected output.

```
s = [["ham", "swiss"], ["turkey", "cheddar"], ["roast beef", "gruyere"]]
i = 0;
s.each{
    |array| so = array[i] # pin
    puts so[i]
    }
```

Due to #pin, if i = 0, output is h t r. i = 1 gives w h r. i > 1 gives an error:

```
C:/Ruby.rb in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby.rb:3:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

If I use `|array| so = array # pin`, then my code does not produce strange output. I'll just fix the remaining stuff to make my code iterate for all values that 'i' can have.

Please explain this.

PS: Working code is here

```
s = [["ham", "swiss"], ["turkey", "cheddar"], ["roast beef", "gruyere"]]
s.each{
  |array| so = array
  array.each{
  |str| puts str   
  }
}
```

Comment: What you are seeing is the result of getting array values that are out of range.  Use array.fetch(i) and you will get a more helpful error. I generally use fetch for array and hash lookup so you don't get strange x was called on nil:NilClass

Comment: @Joeyjoejoejr - thanks. but as a beginner, I am confused why ruby behaves like this.

Comment: Why are people so nasty here ? What is the -1 for and where is the reason ? If you think a question is of poor quality and must be deleted, then I will gladly comply. But, I need a reason first.

Answer (score 0):

For each type of sandwich, when i is 0, so is the 1st element, which is the meat. so[0] is the first letter of the meat.

When i is 1, which is the 2nd element, which is the cheese. so[1] is the second letter of the cheese.

When i is 3, there is no third component to the sandwich. so so is nil. so[2] is asking for the nil[2].

nil is a class, like everything in ruby. But nil does not implement the [] method, as arrays and other classes that implement the Enumerable module do.

Since nil does not support the [] method, then you get the undefined method error.

Even operations that are built into other languages, like +, [], and == are methods that can be overridden in Ruby.

To understand exactly what's happening, try this bit of code:

```
class NilClass
  def [] (i)
    nil
  end
end
```

Executing that will open up the existing NilClass, and add a method called []. Then you can do nil[1] and it will return nil. Changing an existing class like this is known as *monkey patching* in the Ruby world.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for `so[2]` you are actually asking for the third element, and if it doesn't exist, you'll get an error.

I recommend structuring your blocks like so:

```
s.each do |pair|
  puts pair
end
```

Note the `do/end` instead of `{}` and the placement of the iteration variable inline with the `each`. Also note that this is equivalent to your "working code" so you don't need the extra iterator in this case.